# Allow C++ constants to be a default function parameter using Rcpp Attributes

Tags: r, rcpp

I created a cumsum function in an R package with rcpp which will cumulatively sum a vector until it hits the user defined ceiling or floor. However, if one wants the cumsum to be bounded above, the user must still specify a floor.

Example:

```
a = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

If i wanted to cumsum `a` and have an upper bound of 3, I could `cumsum_bounded(a, lower = 1, upper = 3)`. I would rather not have to specify the lower bound.

My code:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <cmath>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector cumsum_bounded(NumericVector x, int upper, int lower) {
  NumericVector res(x.size());
  double acc = 0;
  for (int i=0; i < x.size(); ++i) {
    acc += x[i];
    if (acc < lower)  acc = lower;
    else if (acc > upper)  acc = upper;
    res[i] = acc;
  }
  return res;
}
```

What I would like:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <climits> //for LLONG_MIN and LLONG_MAX
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector cumsum_bounded(NumericVector x, long long int upper = LLONG_MAX, long long int lower = LLONG_MIN) {
  NumericVector res(x.size());
  double acc = 0;
  for (int i=0; i < x.size(); ++i) {
    acc += x[i];
    if (acc < lower)  acc = lower;
    else if (acc > upper)  acc = upper;
    res[i] = acc;
  }
  return res;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, yes its possible but it requires finesse that involves creating an intermediary function or embedding sorting logic within the main function.

---

In long, Rcpp attributes only supports a limit feature set of values. These values are listed in the [Rcpp FAQ 3.12 entry](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-FAQ.pdf#page=16)

> - String literals delimited by quotes (e.g. "foo")
> - Integer and Decimal numeric values (e.g. 10 or 4.5)
> - Pre-defined constants including:
>
>   - Booleans: true and false
>   - Null Values: R_NilValue, NA_STRING, NA_INTEGER, NA_REAL, and NA_LOGICAL.
> - Selected vector types can be instantiated using the
>     empty form of the ::create static member function.
>
>   - CharacterVector, IntegerVector, and NumericVector
> - Matrix types instantiated using the rows, cols constructor Rcpp::Matrix n(rows,cols)
>
>   - CharacterMatrix, IntegerMatrix, and NumericMatrix)

If you were to specify numerical values for `LLONG_MAX` and `LLONG_MIN` this would meet the criteria to directly use Rcpp attributes on the function.  However, these values are implementation specific. Thus, it would not be ideal to hardcode them. Thus, we have to seek an outside solution: the `Rcpp::Nullable<T>` class to enable the default `NULL` value. The reason why we have to wrap the parameter type with `Rcpp::Nullable<T>` is that `NULL` is a very special and can cause heartache if not careful.

The `NULL` value, unlike others on the real number line, will not be used to bound your values in this case. As a result, it is the perfect candidate to use on the function call. There are two choices you then have to make: use `Rcpp::Nullable<T>` as the parameters on the main function or create a "logic" helper function that has the correct parameters and can be used elsewhere within your application without worry. I've opted for the later below.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <climits> //for LLONG_MIN and LLONG_MAX
using namespace Rcpp;

NumericVector cumsum_bounded_logic(NumericVector x,
                                   long long int upper = LLONG_MAX,
                                   long long int lower = LLONG_MIN) {

    NumericVector res(x.size());
    double acc = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < x.size(); ++i) {
        acc += x[i];
        if (acc < lower)  acc = lower;
        else if (acc > upper)  acc = upper;
        res[i] = acc;
    }

    return res;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector cumsum_bounded(NumericVector x,
                             Rcpp::Nullable<long long int> upper = R_NilValue, 
                             Rcpp::Nullable<long long int> lower = R_NilValue) {

    if(upper.isNotNull() && lower.isNotNull()){
        return cumsum_bounded_logic(x, Rcpp::as< long long int >(upper), Rcpp::as< long long int >(lower));
    } else if(upper.isNull() && lower.isNotNull()){
        return cumsum_bounded_logic(x, LLONG_MAX, Rcpp::as< long long int >(lower));
    } else if(upper.isNotNull() && lower.isNull()) {
        return cumsum_bounded_logic(x, Rcpp::as< long long int >(upper), LLONG_MIN);
    } else {
        return cumsum_bounded_logic(x, LLONG_MAX, LLONG_MIN);
    }

    // Required to quiet compiler
    return x;
}
```

---

Test Output

```
cumsum_bounded(a, 5)
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5 5 5
cumsum_bounded(a, 5, 2)
## [1] 2 3 4 5 5 5 5
```

Comment: I get the following error when building the package: `Warning messages:
1: Unable to parse C++ default value 'LLONG_MAX' for argument upper of function cumsum_bounded_logic 
2: Unable to parse C++ default value 'LLONG_MIN' for argument lower of function cumsum_bounded_logic `

Comment: Copy and paste exactly what I have above. Do not add `// [[Rcpp::export]` to the `cumsum_bounded_logic` function..

Comment: Thank you, I had a lingering `// [[Rcpp::export]`.